# Norm estimation of a function on Hilbert space implies linear transformation has closed range

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I want to prove the following fact:

> Let $T: X\to Y$ be a bounded linear transformation between two Hilbert spaces $X$ and $Y$. Show that if there exists a constant $C$ such that $\|f\| \leq C \|T^*f\|$ then linear transformation $T$ has closed range.

My attempt: I was going to take a function $g \in Y$ and define a linear functional $l (T^*f) = <f,g>_Y$ and try to first prove that $l$ is continuous on $\text{Ran}(T^*$ and go from there.

I don't know if my direction is correct. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that this is the original question?

Comment: Well it's an if and only if question, but I proved the other direction and need help with this direction

Comment: From your inequality it follows that $T^*$ has closed range. Can you use the closed range theorem (which states that $T$ has closed range if and only if $T^*$ has closed range)?

Answer (score 1):

If a bounded linear operator $A : E\to F$ between Banach spaces $E$ and $F$ satisfies an inequality $\|Ax\|\ge C\|x\|$ for all $x\in E$, then it is injective and its range is closed. This can be proved with a Cauchy sequence argument. The converse implication also holds.

Now, your $T^*$ has this property. Let $f\in Y$. Then
$$
\|TT^*f\|\|f\|\ge\langle TT^*f,f\rangle = \|T^*f\|^2\ge C^{-2}\|f\|^2.
$$
Note that $T^*$ maps $Y$ bijectively onto its range, so $T^{-*} : ran(T^*)\to Y$ exists and is bounded. Let $f\in Y$ as before and set $g:=T^*f\in ran(T^*)$. Then
$$
\|Tg\| = \|TT^*f\|\ge C^{-2}\|f\| = C^{-2}\|T^{-*}g\|\ge C^{-2}\|T^*\|^{-1}\|g\|.
$$
Therefore, $T|ran(T^*)$ has closed range. But as $ran(T^*) = \ker(T)^\perp$, and thus $ran(T|ran(T^*)) = ran(T)$, we conclude that $ran(T)$ is closed.